# My disk has only 1 GB free - how can I use the Linux Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: wallets, ubuntu, memory

I just downloaded the Ethereum Wallet for Debian Linux (I have Ubuntu 16.04).
It appears to be downloading a lot of blocks: it now says that there are 3,310,606 blocks, and the number is decreasing. I also see a new .ethereum folder in my home folder, which is now over 602 MB in size and increasing.

I am almost out of memory on my laptop. Is there a way to use Ethereum (including some simple smart contracts) without using so much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Chrome plugin Metamask https://metamask.io/ then you do not need to download a full node, but can use theirs.

For contracts try to use Remix (online Solidity IDE) https://remix.ethereum.org

Comment: You mean to use Metamask instead of the official Ethereum Wallet? Does it mean that my money will be stored on their computers? I prefer to store my money on my computer... heard it is safer.

Comment: Your "Money" will neither be on your computer nor on theirs. It's in the blockchain. You can Import your keystore file whereever you want. Export your keystore file from the Ethereum Wallet and Import your address in the Metamask plugin. Your account is save whatever you use as a wallet, as long a you keep your keysore files and don't forget your password.